# .NET 6 - Create Identity Context on Existing Database

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I am new to .NET and learning how to create Identity and Login pages. I have the database context `Database1DbContext` for testing and it has a couple tables already.

I followed tutorials to add `builder.Services.AddIdentity`, IdentityUser, IdentityRole... in the `Programs.cs`. The `DbContext` requires to inherit from `IdentityDbContext` and I am not sure how to re-use the existing `public class Database1DbContext : DbContext`, so I ended up create another

```
public class IdentityDatabase1DbContext : IdentityDbContext
```

which is pointing to the same database connection (see below code).

Here is the code in the `DbContext.cs` file:

```
public class Database1DbContext : DbContext
{
    public Database1DbContext(DbContextOptions<Database1DbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<TransactionModel> Transactions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class IdentityDatabase1DbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public IdentityDatabase1DbContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityDatabase1DbContext> options)
       : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

This code is in the `Program.cs` file:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<Database1DbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnDatabase1")));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<IdentityDatabase1DbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnDatabase1")));
    
    
// For Identity
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDatabase1DbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// Adding Authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});
```

I did the `add-migration`, `update-database` and it created `AspNetUsers`, `AspNetRoles`... tables and everything works fine.

However, the way I did seem duplicated/inefficient because I created duplicate context and entries multiple places.

Is there a way to make `Database1DbContext` inherit both `DbContext` and `IdentityDbContext` or somehow make it more efficient?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Is there a way to make `Database1DbContext` inherit both `DbContext` and `IdentityDbContext`_ ->   `IdentityDbContext` is already a subclass of `DbContext`  so by having your context inherit  `IdentityDbContext` you also inherit `DbContext` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in `DbContext.cs` will be-

```cs
public class Database1DbContext: IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public Database1DbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<TransactionModel> Transactions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

and the code in is in the `Program.cs` file will be-

```cs
// Identity
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<Database1DbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```